# Static cell in UITableViewController not showing content in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm using UITableViewController static cells and added UILabel and text box to it. I even added constraints. But when I run the program the cells are empty.

Here are my screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I Just found out

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
```

above code make it disapear

Comment: post your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: There is no point posting screenshots without code. You need to post code also.

Answer (score 11):

In Swift 2, tested the below fix for the question

'Comment-out' the below auto-generated/boiler plate code that comes along when you subclass UITableViewController (as you are using static cells, they may not be used)

```
  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forget to set `Custom Class` for your `TableViewController`?
Try this:

1. Go to storyboard.
2. Select your `TableViewController`.
3. Go to `Show the identity inspector` (3rd icon in right panel).
4. Set `Class` to your `MyCustomTableViewController` class (if this class doesn't exist, create it).
5. Run your project.

Answer (score 2):

After i updated the following 2 functions `return` it worked again.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 15
}
```

Comment: It also works if you just delete these overriden functions and let the definition of the storyboard take control... the values you set in the Table View's Attribute Inspector (x Sections) and Table View Section's Attribute Inspector (x Rows).

Edit: Just saw Naishta's answer. Maybe you can accept Naishta's answer as correct, it should have solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using static cell with custom layout as you are here, the class for the tableview should not be your custom tableviewcontroller class. Try and set your tableview and cell as the dumps below.
If you, on the other hand, wants to fill the cell content dynamically, you need to make a class for the custom cell and also handle the filling of the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath and also use dynamic prototype cells. Apple has some good explanations [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

[image: UITableViewController]

[image: UITableViewCell]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't defined data source and delegate
This might help you.
https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Table-View-Guide

Answer (score 0):

[image]   And

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
            return 3
        }
```